# Proof with exponent

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How do I prove that

$$1+be^b \leq e^b$$

If I know that $b\geq0$.

My idea:

I thought writing it as $f(x) = 1+be^b - e^b$. Derivative of this function is $f'(x) = be^b$. We have minima at $b=0$.

Comment: If $b\geq 1$, then clearly $be^b\geq e^b$...

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $1+be^b\geq be^b$?

Comment: Mistake $b\geq0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the function $f(b)=1+be^b-e^b$ has a minimum value at $b=0$; therefore,
$$
1+be^b-e^b = f(b) \geq f(0) = 0
$$
for all $b$, which means
$$
1+be^b \geq e^b
$$
for all $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x) = e^x$ on the interval $[0,b]$. By the mean value theorem there exists $c$ such that $ 0 < c < b$ and $$ \frac{f(b)-f(0)}{b-0} = f'(c) $$

The left-hand side is $\frac{e^b-1}{b}$ and the right-hand side is $e^c$, which is $\leq e^b$. Therefore,
$$
    \frac{e^b-1}{b} \leq e^b \implies e^b - 1 \leq be^b \implies e^b \leq 1 + be^b
$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b\geq 1$ then $be ^b / e^b = b \geq 1 \implies be^b\geq e^b$. Therefore,
$$1+be^b \geq be^b \geq e^b$$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake $b\geq0$.

Answer (score -1):

The inequality you want to prove is wrong but the converse one,
$$
e^b\le 1+be^b
$$
holds ***for all*** $b\,$ (in a [previous conversation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852270/conservatism-of-bounds?noredirect=1#comment10339929_4852270) you told me that you can prove that):
\begin{align}
f(b)&=1+be^b-e^b\,,&f'(b)&=be^b\,,&f''(b)=(1+b)e^b\,.
\end{align}
Since $f'(b)=0$ at $b=0$ and $f''(0)\ge 0$ the function $f$ has a local minimum at $0\,.$ Since $f'\ge 0$ on $b\ge 0$ the point $b=0$ is a global minimum on $b\ge 0\,.$ From $f(0)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{b\to-\infty}f(b)=1\ge 0$ it follows that $f$ cannot be negative for $b<0$ because otherwise it must have another minimum on the negative $b$-axis. But $b=0$ is obviously the only point with $f'(b)=0\,.$